Refresh navbar username after user updates username in settings
In Next.js, I have a navbar in app/(dashboard)/layout.tsx that displays the user's name.
In app/(dashboard)/(settings)/settings/user-form.tsx, the user can change their name (so it's saved to database).
Now, I want the navbar to refresh and display the new name when the user changes it in settings. Because now the name in the navbar doesn't change after the user updates the username.
How can I achieve this? It seems to be a common issue, but I'm new to React/Next.js, so I don't know what the right way to do this is.

can you provide a [mcve] of how you are storing the details and retrieving them for your components?

is it good to use redux in this case ?

It depends. What do you have?

i think it's pretty clear all is said in the question

You haven’t explained how your data is being accessed or updated.

Where are you storing the username?

I'm using NextAuth, so the username comes from the session

In this case, I would use the createContext hook and use it with useContext.
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

export function Sidebar() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <SidebarNav />
      <Settings />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

function SidebarNav() {
  let { user } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Home</p>

      {user.name}
    </div>
  );
} 

This is an example from (https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs), which I changed a bit to use it in for your example.
What does createContext do?
A context in React behaves the same as a useState, but by wrapping the context provider around a component, the wrapped component and all its child component have now acces to the context, without the need to pass the props. For example even the 100th child of the component, can use the user context, by calling useContext(UserContext).
How can I change the user context inside a child component?
function Settings() {
   let {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext); 

   return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => setUser("new-name")}>Change User Name to new-name</button>
    </div>
   );
}

If you click on the button, the context is updated and everywhere the user context is used, the component is rerendered -> The Navbar is now seen with the new user name.
Please note: I am not 100% sure if the code inside the Settings is working, it is just to illustrated how it should look like, I advise to read more in https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext .

yes chatgpt told me to do this too, but what is the difference between this and redux ?

I have never used Redux, but 1 year ago I had the job to compare redux, with other state management tools, what would be the best use case inside our react application. My end result was: useContext, useState, useReducer ... all this hooks that come with react are enough to handle state management inside a react app. But if you have a lot of complex states inside your app and they need to be centralized (inside one file, I think it is in redux), redux is the choice. But at the end its depending on what you want to achieve.

the username is retrieved from useSession, do you think i should put username in context ? or i should update the session ?

I have no clue of how useSession works in react, but by looking into the docs a bit, you should have the possiblity, to update the session (-> the username as well) and you then dont need to use the context. If this is not working, context is a great choice in my opinion.
